# React props discriminative union vs conditional type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, union-types

I am scratching my head around why a conditional type I made for a component's props is not working, but a discriminative union is working as expected.

The example can be found in this [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZFLIBmcAvnHVBCHAERSoacDcAKFCRYuOACF8MGBAB22KTPkAFNmELYAkmnlLZCuAFkkc-ExZsOnAAJykEACwArALRyAJgBsA9D3QwAsLg0PAwAJ5gSOI6etIGahAa2ADC8pQAHjAmZokaFqzsXHYOLu7efryBQoIRUXAAghjA8igARl5IACqR0QC8XG3x8pxwAD5cwLpy%20iM1ddFNMC1y7Z15hAA8XXBIWaYehI3NrR3dvQB8cAM4gnBcHhQorpSEyx6cAFxwb1DAcgBzITMABkcB2e0oniOnCGyjkox8PjgqygbAA7v8AXAABYoMBRORHHFIHhwQC8G4AJHbucAA-HAAPIgYAwTazOQbbCceQpLxTADWowm3CQdCFXDQOOAXg8PARVzBt3u9wAXir2V1Id92RsANqcSXS2WmTgAXSE90YNO%20TJZm1iM2GHPUmi4PL5aEF4y4PDF3oNUplcs4CtwNNVKod3wdOpd%20sNQZN5ppjHmvTgaU8LJWKC8SxzZw2212%202hx2Wp06PSiVxuNICBarvW%20XQtcAblaQG2%20%20c7Ra6F2BafqvdWZwA6iycTl8P2S1DDuXG%20ca9caZmPNnWnmTmP1i7tqGlcqQKZZy6bczWeHlZnMtkz5yb-duYTxdy5LyIMR3yg5JLoAAUS8d9fXfBNjQRG9BxvCC5W%20O9IRnPUAyNYNk0tGpBGmN4M3kTcK1WLw0hCew5HgAZi0hA4jlHNYV36SZpnZEMAApjw7PcGMwetd3op97lPXIXR4%2044NMHjGB7PiJynZCDwHABKa4rmPHD4F1YBCBnBlCWwYgYC0bSz100xTWuAhiDICgkFYuhc2IRS23UuAhPwBp-xxaB6Asmh6FYswvC8JzBBpTp4E4%20jvgAKRIAANAA6YCkCEmAanuYAGFYyKzmrfo%20gGTgpjieFOGU48xPkXC8DVB1sAShqeFw5gBhy-ckkIfg4CRClKTgdEcXCdsZPa-ItJRCB4FRDEkA8G82sY%201mKdXAGoSpqYEYC4cFq6ZGE2HwYydGDLV2LxiDDZU4Bcmr1SdTUsnqxqkGaiyFo2Nt7gWiy2RWnA1o2radru%20EHs2g72ROphQppHgYHwKA5DgVib02C5n1wBarSu%205NhnDH7iSUw%20hwLSdMJOAQTBABCam3I8gCoHoBK0ARuVNoJuB3W-JASdY5S%20iuAyjPJ0w7IcpBFOxnGvs8oCvBJ%20m5aZ0UWbZ0wOZl9GZfuHBxLkaWroOmdteVA7TZC1NQoWOAAFU5BWCyOJGhjvlhJ0gi%20l3u0ZK9fvhTk3U-D0vWFMD-X1kNKcu5U1Q1LVJCdFDI4w6HpYmCrhsI%20i8rd4rHVKz6s%20XH3bVZI6A5EoPeQFUDRXAwNIKjxUMd2%20Ro2WyuOvjRv0KL6WrdqdM6NkmBp0fF0ACY13ue3HZbq63NLv2McQrJ5I60ScdfE1-W5n9-T-RngLrv1hUj6Ci-1hD0iQifu9QxMEVTwfsKq%20A555dhIDIijked7OuVehb3eiJGkS8wFiV7hJQQUklydknGPDeGhJ4C1UjSFymljJmFMoYYW2D8C4PMgMGg1lKDi3OpLZy79XJngZl5FWDASHEH8oFYK6U4DhWLp2GK8UkqdFShwzKyMFp5WuAVJiJUDBlRjpVIk8Bbp1TgADF68AWrcK4h9bqyIqQaP4i6OA40wDqFJF4Ia00IDolmvNF2P0K4GFWs9N4QM24GwOvY%20QUNmBIEobI66NDbrx0esopxai3rexdEXb6lF2SOPWqolxIMDBg32j4SGbYrShXuHDBGSMUZG1NldHAWMMZ4zPJzImcgSZkxMhTKmcBaZK0ZszVmaINaGxxvvXmOB%20YqR%20EgQyBDcEUMch0q6R8GHAUVnQ5WLT1bkTGXAQpOM9bQINqUnwJtUY%20AtkOGGMMXKalwgMXpgtkY0k2JuAAbssnqjQ4BwgcZiMehjphwGMUTWAQ0wAoEIMQOaRsNxbiIiRH%20Gs9FAKiH0d2pUMagI6iTTOV1NyEHoh4b4MAoD4CoJzBsVykAYqxdEHq%20Z8VwA8BAF6E14B7C0vAf4PwRCdAeU6LJONGBbSOfAdkB0gXZ2It-eQGt0Y3juQ0fq0B%20RYhZfCVGfKcwCtIuC0RvRoWPJGHCiJCKcBIuVCitFhLsVbxlnHe6CdOAAAkkBDTHqSJAnAMYcoxhA7VOAnVXQuOOSV0qeU%20HlduUFQryIiqumKpG%20cZVPKnK8%20Q7yTFfPeb8-5cr8LAtzIG3%20EKmxQqKp3aRWauwukRcXfFhqqBwFcd8S5wAbldBQAda5VwOW0OEq6jlFwuVwAdIneEvLU38ozcKmGobkSfyRoO8iqMx0Toii7PKaqPaasAaNQgiLOb6rOOiuAmKjWcx6nigl26iXaKXGSilVK5CTRLHSwxSNCBMuiOquQnNTWgwTtWm5rxWQ%20EbWyq67qcYuo0IigDHrO2%20unYK3%20IblRiolVAKVgJI3yCnQ7L%20SryIFvnTC6RS6S5Fp1eurSBqj27p1hWpJ8gwZuytTakkPAHUy1Ayee%20wGdXMc9d6pDEG0Ofig0O0VyJGjhreU%20-q0aI0fKiAmn5fzrFG0gxh2dy6GLQvzixAtGxi0HrLdgStcAP0dvrT%20mtTbmBAdXexzlqiu1vJ4ysGdMGG2mcEIpUKQA)

Am I doing something wrong, or there is some react context which I am missing?

A snippet from the playground is bellow:

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Button, ButtonProps, IconButton, Menu } from "@neo4j-ndl/react";
import type { IconButtonProps, ContextMenuProps } from "@neo4j-ndl/react";

type ActionableType = "button" | "iconButton";

type ActionableProps<T extends ActionableType> = {
  "data-testid": string;
} & T extends "button" // narrowing happens here 
  ? Omit<ButtonProps, "onClick" | "ref" | "children"> & {
    zzButtonText: ButtonProps["children"];
  }
  : Omit<IconButtonProps, "onClick" | "ref" | "children"> & {
    zzIcon: IconButtonProps["children"];
  };

type ConditionalActionableProps<T extends ActionableType> = {
  actionableType: T;
  actionableProps: ActionableProps<T>;
};

type ActionableWithMenuProps<T extends ActionableType> =
  ConditionalActionableProps<T> & {
    menuProps: Omit<
      ContextMenuProps,
      "open" | "onClose" | "anchorEl" | "ref" | "children"
    >;
    children: ContextMenuProps["children"];
  };


const ConditionalComponent = <T extends ActionableType = "iconButton">({
  actionableType,
  actionableProps,
  menuProps,
  children,
}: ActionableWithMenuProps<T>) => {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const menuAnchorRef = useRef(null);

  let actionable: JSX.Element;

  if (actionableType === "iconButton") {
    const { zzIcon, ...rest } = actionableProps; //  why actionableProps is not narrowed
    actionable = <IconButton {...rest}>{zzIcon}</IconButton>;
  } else {
    const { zzButtonText, ...rest } = actionableProps;
    actionable = <Button {...rest}>{zzButtonText}</Button>;
  }


  return (
    <>
      {actionable}
      <Menu
        open={isMenuOpen && !!menuAnchorRef.current}
        onClose={() => setIsMenuOpen(false)}
        anchorEl={menuAnchorRef.current}
      >
        {children}
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The type

```
type ConditionalActionableProps<T extends ActionableType> = {
    actionableType: T;
    actionableProps: ActionableProps<T>;
};
```

means

```
type ConditionalActionableProps = {
    actionableType: "button" | "iconButton";
    actionableProps: ActionableProps<"button" | "iconButton">;
};
```

because the type is still generic and not yet narrowed when defining

```
const ConditionalComponent = <T extends ActionableType = "iconButton">({
    actionableType,
    actionableProps,
    menuProps,
    children,
}: ActionableWithMenuProps<T>) => { ...
```

so discrimination based on actionableType breaks. This does narrow the type as desired:

```
type ConditionalActionableProps<T extends ActionableType> =
    T extends 'button'
    ? {
        actionableType: T;
        actionableProps: ActionableProps<T>
    }
    : T extends 'iconButton'
    ? {
        actionableType: T;
        actionableProps: ActionableProps<T>
    } : never
```

but it is verbose